# Aws s3 event don't support multiple events for same bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i want on s3 put bucket should emit multiple events i.e lambda,sqs & sns services. i tried single service to emit on bucket put. but now i want multiple service to be emitted by bucket on put. to perform different task.
how can i achieve this, i googled it but no use.
any help will be appreciated.
thank you in advance.

Comment: thanks for asking this question. i too was wondering how to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best bet can be to use something like `Fanout` scenario.

Create a topic using `SNS` and your bucket can publish a message to this `topic` on `put` Event.

`Lambda and SQS` can subscribe to this `SNS` topic. Whenever topic gets message, it will be received by all subscribers. Lambda will be invoked and queue will receive message, along with other subscriber(s).

[SQS And SNS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-subscribe-queue-sns-topic.html)

Comment: Note that SNS Fanout is now more flexible, with [Subscription Filters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/message-filtering.html).  All messages no longer necessarily go to all subscribers.